# How to create repository in github through github API?

Tags: git, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to use github api to create repositories under a particular organization. I was looking at this [site](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) which talks about how to create repositories under a particular organization.

```
Create a new repository in this organization. The authenticated user must be a member of the specified organization.
POST /orgs/:org/repos
```

Now I am not able to understand what will be my full URL that I need to use to create the repository under a particular organization? I have my username and password which I can use to create the repository under an organization through https url.

My github instance url is like this - `https://github.host.com`

And I want my repository to be like this after getting created -

```
https://github.host.com/Database/ClientService
```

What will be my curl command look like to create the repository under an organization?

Comment: All the information you need is **[here](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository)**, describes in the gihub help pages https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. What is token here? And how I will get the token? Sorry for asking stupid question, working for the first time so not sure.

Comment: Read here how to do it: 
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

Answer (score 25):

Go to **Settings** ->  **Developer Settings**  ->  **Personal Access Token**  Under OAuth Apps. Now, Generate a New Access token with Required privileges enabled.
 *Ignore This if you already have one.*

#### User Account:

Replace `ACCESS_TOKEN` with `Token` and `NEW_REPO_NAME` with your New Repository `Name` in the command below:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ACCESS_TOKEN" --data '{"name":"NEW_REPO_NAME"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

#### Organization:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ACCESS_TOKEN" --data '{"name":"NEW_REPO_NAME"}' https://api.github.com/orgs/ORGANIZATION_NAME/repos
```

Comment: What is the priviledge to create a repo?

Answer (score 15):

Step 1: Create a personal `access token` and use it in place of password

Step 2: On command line use the given API as a `POST` request

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/<organisation_name>/repos?access_token=<generated token>
```

or

```
https://api.github.com/user/<username>/repos?access_token=<generated token>
```

In body, pass this as a payload:

```
{
  "name": "<Repo Name>",
  "description": "<Some message>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": false,
}
```

You can pass other details. 
For more details: [click here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create)

Comment: this method is no longer supported - cannot add access tokens in the url. you will have to use  Authorization headers

Comment: If using Insomnia, one can still use this kind of url and JSON payload - just put the token inside as Bearer type auth.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new solution official from [cli.github.com](https://cli.github.com/). The other answers are deprecated.

First Install GitHub CLI. Run:

```
brew install gh
```

Then to create a repository with a specific name. Enter the following command:

```
gh repo create --private my-project
```

Here is the official documentation [link](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create) to create a repo.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new repo in github for Enterprise this worked for me:

Please change the value in angular brackets before executing. Put `username:token` after `-u`

```
curl -u https://github.com/api/v3/orgs/<org-name>/repos -d '{"name":"<reponame>"}
```

Comment: In my case, our company has a custom github domain; for sake of argument pretend our github domain is "stuff.tinycorp.localdomain".  I had to replace "github.com" above with "stuff.tinycorp.localdomain".  Otherwise, quite a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the two above answers, here's a `bash >=4.2` script to create a clone a repo.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TOKEN=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

if [[ $# < 3 ]]; then
    echo "arguments: $0 <RepoName> <RepoDescription>"
    exit 1
fi

REPO_NAME=$1; shift
REPO_DESCRIPTION="$@"

echo "Name: $REPO_NAME"
echo "Description: $REPO_DESCRIPTION"
echo "Calling GitHub to create repo"

read -r -d '' PAYLOAD <<EOP
{
  "name": "$REPO_NAME",
  "description": "$REPO_DESCRIPTION",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/$REPO_NAME",
  "private": false
}
EOP

shopt -s lastpipe
curl -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" --data "$PAYLOAD" \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos | readarray output

url=''
for line in "${output[@]}"; do
    echo -n "$line"
    #   "html_url": "https://github.com/sfinktah/vim-hex-sum",
    if [[ $line == *html_url* ]]; then
        l=${line#*\"}; l=${l#*\"}; l=${l#*\"}; url=${l%\"*}
    fi
done

count=0
[[ $url == http*://*github.com/* ]] &&
    until git clone $url; do 
        sleep 10; (( count++ > 5 )) && break; echo Waiting...
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer this is an old method,
without installing github cli

create repo in terminal directly with api

replace userName and repoName

> `curl -u "userNameHere" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d > '{"name":"repoNameHere","private":true}'`

enter password and done

for more info refer new official doc [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create)

Answer (score 0):

Recommend [Github SDK Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js). To create a repository:

```
const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: `personal-access-token123` });

// Create a repo for user.
octokit.rest.repos.createForAuthenticatedUser({
  name,
});

// Create a repo in an organization.
octokit.rest.repos.createInOrg({
  org,
  name,
});
```