# How does Github Pages add a subdomain for each repository?

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, digital-ocean

For every single github repository like `https://github.com/user/repository` there is a corresponding github pages subdomain `repository.github.io`, and github just creates these subdomains under `github.io` on the fly.

Anyone know how github does this?  I'm hoping there exists an easy to use DNS server / DNS Service that is also REST capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that GitHub is just using a [wildcard subdomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) that maps from `*.github.io` to some internal GitHub server, which then serves the correct repository based on the requested URL.

I don't know what you're trying to do with GitHub's DNS server, but you can create a repo via the GitHub API: [How to create repository in github through github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385884/how-to-create-repository-in-github-through-github-api)