# create repo using github api (only curl and no oauth)

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to create a github repo using the v3 api, but I always get a `Not Found` error. I want to do it only with curl and without oauth. This is what I'm trying:

```
curl -u myusername https://api.github.com/users/repos -d '{"name": "reponame"}'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without an Access Token. 
Also, please feel free to look at my GitHub open source project [Git-Captain](https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain).

I created a web-application with a Node.js back-end and HTML/JS front-end that you can setup to have an API do many of these calls for you. It has a step-by-step for a windows server and I'll be adding a Linux step-by-step soon.

It would only take a slight tweak to the project to add a new end-point to the source to do this for you.

To answer your question,

The GitHub API documentation explains exactly how to do what you are requesting [on this link](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/getting-started/#create-a-repository).

Giving this example:

as you requested in CURL and obviously replace the token "5199..." with your own:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: token 5199831f4dd3b79e7c5b7e0ebe75d67aa66e79d4" \
    -d '{ \
        "name": "blog", \
        "auto_init": true, \
        "private": true, \
        "gitignore_template": "nanoc" \
      }' \
    https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

---

OR

Not in CURL and according to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385884/how-to-create-repository-in-github-through-github-api) you can do the following:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/<organisation_name>/repos?access_token=<generated token>
       or
https://api.github.com/users/<username>/repos?access_token=<generated token>
```

In body, pass this as a payload:

```
{
  <br/>"name": "<Repo Name>",<br/>
  "description": "<Whateveryour description is>",<br/>
  "homepage": "https://github.com",<br/>
  "private": false,<br/>
}
```

You can get a "personal access token in GitHub" by going to `Settings->Developer Settings-> Personal Access Tokens->Generate new token`

[image: In Settings->Developer Settings-> Personal Access Tokens->Generate new token]

---

OR do all of the following

- Write a script (let's call this script #1) that takes the username,password, and repoName as a parameter.
- That script will call script #2, which is `curl -u ' USER-NAME-HERE' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name": "REPO-NAME-HERE"}'` which will prompt for your user password,
- have your script #1 listen for script #2's response and then have it enter in the password which the user passed in as a parameter in script#1
- Finally programmatically hit enter which fires off the curl to create your repo.

**UPDATE***

So for some reason, the CURL won't work at all, but the Git-Hub API end point `https://api.github.com/user/repos` does indeed work. Using [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/), I was able to create a new POST with the URL being `https://api.github.com/user/repos` and the BODY set to:

```
{
  "name": "Hello-World",
  "description": "This is your first repository",
  "homepage": "https://github.com",
  "private": false,
  "has_issues": true,
  "has_projects": true,
  "has_wiki": true
}
```

Then I went to the 'Authorization' section of postman and under 'Type' I selected "Basic Auth" entered my username and password.
Clicked update request and then send and my repo was created!

Comment: I wanted to avoid the authorization token step because to be honest I don't even know how to get one. Is that something I can set up in my account to give access to my data to external apps? Or is it something I have to get with another command to the API?

Comment: Both. setup in your GitHub account and do a call to the API. I setup a Oauth App in Github, once I set that up I got a "client id" and a "client secret". Then you use that "client ID" to request a "user authorization code". Once you have that user authorization code then you can request a access token, once you have that access token (never expires) you can whatever.  Technically, you can do all this using curl,postman,Firefox, or fiddler. Any tool that has HTTP verbs (post, get,put, delete). In my Git-Captain GitHub project look at step "Create New oAuth App in GitHub" step.

Comment: The easier solution for you would be to create a "Personal access token", instead of the GitHub Oauth App.You can do that in the developer settings in GitHub.

Comment: I've updated the answer, with info on how to create your access token in Settings->Developer Settings-> Personal Access Tokens->Generate new token

Comment: The authorization token worked. However, the reason why I wanted to create a repo with the API was to create a bash script to easily create repos from the command line. The token approach would require me to hard-code the token into the script, which I don't feel very comfortable with, especially because I save my utility scripts in a git repo that lives in a server that isn't managed by me. What would be a better way? I've used the bitbucket API before where it's as simple as sending a request to the API with regular authentication that asks for your password every time you execute it.

Comment: @yewang I would recommend you setup a Oauth App in Github as I stated in my previous comment. I was trying to do something similar to what your doing as well, but ended up creating a Node.js server with an API and a HTML/JS front end that authenticates users via GitHub.

Comment: @yewang Actually after more research, what you were doing should have worked, did it prompt you for password? See my latest updated answer.

Comment: I just discovered that -d '{"name": "reponame"}' has to go before the URL. I tried that and it worked.