# After adding existing git repo to github.com, not visible from inside github.com

Tags: git, github

I added a local existing git repo to github.com as a remote via the command

```
% git remote add origin https://github.com/username/synchm.git
```

and confirmed it with

```
% git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/username/synchm.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/synchm.git (push)
```

However when I log into **github.com/username** the new repository is not visible, not even after and hour.

I tried entering

```
https://github.com/username/synchm.git
```

but it redirected to

```
https://github.com/username/synchm.git
```

and returned a 404.

What's going on?

Comment: Read this https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line. Think this article will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create the repository trough the github website and then push your local.

What you're doing is merely telling your local git configuration where the `origin` remote is located.

After creating the repository on github and setting the `origin` remote you still need to push your local branch before it will be visible on github. `git push origin master` (replace master with your current branch name).

Comment: You are exactly right.  As a point of interest only, creating on the github side is apparently also possible though github API, e.g. using **curl** as shown in (this answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/56099606/4376643].