# Python: Selenium cannot find xpath of a page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a little app to make me a new repo for GitHub. It works well until it comes to the page where it should insert repository name, but in that page, it cannot find any elements XPath?

[image]

```
# Write new project name
newProject = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="repository_name"]')
newProject.send_keys('qwerty')
```

Comment: Please provice a [mcve]

Comment: Also...
Why not using GitHub API instead of a Web automation? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28385884/how-to-create-repository-in-github-through-github-api

Comment: Thought it would be fun to watch it doing it

Comment: Ah, ok then! :)
Show us your code and we'll make it work.

Comment: well I don't know is there anything to look for, it basicly open browser (chrome), maximize it, login to my github, click that little icon top right corner, click "your repositories", click new, and now its in "Create a new repository" page, now that line of code I have right now, is the part that won't work, it just won't find the xpath of that element for some reason... even tho I have used this same method with earlier steps...

Comment: What's an error? Invalid xpath or no such element?
Aren't there must be single quotes in xpath?
//*[@id='repository_name']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct locator: `.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repository_name"]')`

May you need `WebDriverWait` like this:

**By xpath**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="repository_name"]')))
newProject = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="repository_name"]')
newProject.send_keys('qwerty')
```

**By id**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'repository_name')))
newProject = driver.find_element_by_id('repository_name')
newProject.send_keys('qwerty')
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Comment: undefined variable By

Comment: please import : `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`